# get image attribute inside element of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following structure i want to get array of all images src attribute

```
<div id="selectable"> 
    <li class="x">
        <img src="\images\1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="x">
        <img src="\images\2.jpg" />  
    </li>
    <li class="x">
        <img src="\images\3.jpg" />  
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var sources = $("#selectable li img").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

Comment: Remember that `this.src` is not (necessarily) the same as `this.getAttribute('src')` or `$(this).attr('src')` (the latter two implied by the question)

Comment: why do we use .get() ?

Answer (score 1):

In plain JS, something like this should work:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("#selectable img");
var img_array = [];

for(var i in images) {
    img_array.push(images[i].src);
}

console.log(img_array);
```

Comment: True. It is identical with `$("#selectable img")`

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this with jquery:

```
$('#selectable').children('li').each(
function(index){
imgSrc[index]=$(this).children('img').attr('src');
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
var img_array = [];
$.each($("#selectable").find('li > img'),function(index,image){


    img_array.push($(image).attr("src"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var srcarray=[];
$( "#selectable .x img" ).each(function( index ) {
  srcarray[index]=$(this).attr('src');
});
alert(srcarray);
```